# What are the major differences between HERE routing API v7 and v8?

Tags: here-api

I'm looking for a list of the major difference between HERE routing APIs v7 and v8?  I cannot seem to find any documentation enumerating them.

Answer (score 0):

The major difference in the usage of routing API with our platform(cloud based product) on which we have also migrated the routing API. In case one is using platform, the API can be utilised with the registry mechanism. you can read about the details in the authentication of documentation. so coming the two services will eventually be done.
https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/dev_guide/topics/get-credentials.html